# Browsing Internet over Android emulator (AVD) failed

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, network-connection

I cannot access Internet on Android emulator. I am developing an app in my college and the college has many restrictions while accessing content over internet. But, google is not blocked. I cannot access google from emulator, in fact I cannot connect to internet but i am able to setup a server over Local Area Network and i am able to connect. Is there any method to resolve this problem?

**I am thinking following solution might solve my problem-**

every request that is sent from emulator should initially be looked by local machine and the request should be sent over internet as if local machine is requesting (Not emulator) and response received by local machine should be sent back to emulator. But I do not know how to make this work. Help me with this

Please let me know what you think . Will this work? or is there any other better solution like playing around internet settings/access points ?

```
private class Background_Zip_Fetch extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>{

    public Handler handler = new GeocoderHandler();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Home.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        String result = null;
        try {
            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                result = sb.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ZipFetch", "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
        }
```

error occurs at

```
List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                latitude, longitude, 1);
```

in Geocoder class error at

```
String ex =  mService.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults,
            mParams, results);
```

error says

```
Unable connect to Geocode java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
```

manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kattulaprasad.near_me_app">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application...
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: put  your code here

Comment: Done @LuizFernandoSalvaterra

Comment: can you put your Android Manifest File as well?

Comment: Done @LuizFernandoSalvaterra